# For what $n$ is it true that any connected, unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be either open or closed ?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For what $n$ is it true that any connected, unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be either open or closed ? Prove the statement for those n for which it is true and found counter examples for all other n?

I do not understand what the question is asking, but my guess would be " $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$" for the simple fact that what else would it be ? Can a set in some dimension $n$ be neither open or closed?

I do know the definitons of "connected", "open", and "unbounded" sets.

any guidance is appreciated ! Thank You in advance

Comment: For any $n$, consider the set $\{(x,0,\ldots,0)\ |\ x > 0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Neal That is an open set.

Comment: When referring to, say, a door in standard English, the door is either open *xor* closed.  Due to mathematicians' recycling of terminology, it can be tempting to assume that this sort of opposing exclusivity carries over to open/closed subsets of topological spaces.  However, it is possible to have subsets that are neither open nor closed as well as subsets that are *both* open and closed.

Comment: @mechanodroid That is an open set ... for which $n$?

Comment: @Neal For $n = 1$ only, sorry.

Comment: It is clear that $n=1$ because for $n\gt1$ you can easily draw counterexamples.

Comment: @KajHansen: I'm sorry, but in standard English, you have to say "either open or closed but not both" (or some such circumlocution): "xor" isn't English. Your observation about the mathematics is quite correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only $n=1$. Consider $(0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, which is neither open nor closed.

Comment: How to prove that it's connected? It's not path connected.

Comment: @mechanodroid Yes it is path connected. It's convex, so the straight line between any point in this subspace and the origin is entirely within the space. It's not only connected, but also star shaped.

Comment: @mechanodroid Are you sure it's not path connected? That would be quite some feat for a convex set.

Comment: Oh, you are right. For some reason I was thinking about $\{0\}\times \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \cup (0,1]\times\{0\}^{n-1}$.

Comment: so how would I go about proving that every connected, unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n>2}$ is open or closed ?

Comment: @J.Jones I think that question has a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Sets can most certainly be neither open nor closed. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the set $(0,1] \times \mathbb{R}$ is connected and unbounded, but neither open nor closed. This example generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $(0,1] \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. However, I think the point of the exercise is that it is true in $\mathbb{R}^1$.